# Ordered Field with BW Property but not having LUB property

Tags: ordered-fields

In an Ordered Field, LUB Property $\implies$ BW Property (i.e Every bounded sequence has a Convergent Subsequence.)
Is the converse true?

Comment: Can you write some more letters and say what BW and LUB is?

Comment: Sorry for that, by BW I mean Every Bounded sequence will have a convergent subsequence. By LUB I mean every bounded subset will have a least upper bound.

Comment: For ordered fields, (1) Dedekind completeness (2) Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (3) Heine-Borel theorem are all equivalent to each other.